# using ant.desing V4.x Select component with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, antd

I am using antd V4 and antd Select is not binding with redux-form. I can bind the data and can select the items.But After selected the items, move to next control or click, all selected items are disappeared.

I am trying to write my own custom wrapping, still the same issue.

I found out that v3 and v4 onChange event is as follow -:

V3.x onChange?: (value: T, option: React.ReactElement | React.ReactElement[]) => void;

V4.x onChange?: (value: ValueType, option: OptionsType[number] | OptionsType) => void;

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-demo-rgsez?file=/index.js)
Anyone using antd V4.x with redux-form-antd?

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 1):

onBlur in v3 return value is a bad design since user can not prevent event bubble like preventDefault or stopPropagation. In v4, it returns the origin event instead.

we pass onBlur={() => { input.onBlur(input.value); }} prop to Select component for now

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with the redux-form and found a solution from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/2768)

worked solution for me is add this  `onBlur={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}` in to redux field